# "&" influence in conversion operator

Tags: c++

I have my custom string in namespace MySpace.

```
namespace MySpace
{

const std::string bws = "hello";

    class string
        {
    public:
        std::string s ;
        string(void) :s(bws) {}
        string(const std::string & _s ) : s(bws) {};
        operator std::string & (void) {return s;}
        };

}
```

What impact makes "&" in conversion to std:string operator?

Operators

```
operator std::string & (void) {return s;}
```

and

```
operator std::string  (void) {return s;}
```

acts the same in this code:

```
MySpace::string f("ddd");
std::string d=f;
std::cout<<d<<std::endl;
```

They both assigns `"hello"` to `d`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You sure?  I think it is...

Comment: @MooingDuck: Why not the viable constructor??

Comment: You do not need the `(void)`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Because `std::string` does not have a constructor that takes `MySpace::string`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Whoops. Annoying red herring, that. Doesn't seem like it needs to be part of the question's testcase.

Comment: That will determine whether a copy or a reference will be returned. In your example it doesn't make a difference, but what if you tried to use an `std::string` function on an `std::string` casted `MySpace::string`? You'd better hope you returned by reference so that the actual string will get changed, not just some copy.

Comment: In this specific usage case you might want to overload operator<< instead..

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that

```
operator std::string  (void) {return s;}
```

returna a copy of `s`, while

```
operator std::string & (void) {return s;}
```

returns a reference to it.

So if you modify the return value in the first case, it will not impact the value of the class variable `s`, but it will do so in the second case.

In general, it is considered a dangerous practice to return class variables by non-const reference.

Comment: Is it? I see nothing wrong with returning a reference to a member in cases like these. Often it's precisely what you want, to provide access to some underlying representation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is OK to refer const reference, but by returning non-const reference we give write access to class internals. So I would say it is not exactly according to the book.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If the conversion operator is const, maybe. But in that case I would return a const string& (if possible)

Comment: Don't be afraid of giving write access to class internals. It's not always bad. Sometimes your class doesn't need to hide everything. Do it when it's appropriate, not because some crappy internet tutorials told you to.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I never said "_do not do it_", there are definitely cases when returning by reference is not a bad thing at all. There are cases when you even do not declare data members `private`. However such decisions rather require special justification.

Comment: @AlexD: It's more common than you think and doesn't really require much "special" justification.

Answer (score 0):

With `&`, a reference to `s` is returned. Otherwise, a copy of `s` is created and returned.

This makes no difference in your example, because the returned reference is used to initialize `d` while `s` is still alive, but it may turn out to be important in real code. One particular problem to keep in mind is that returning a reference can lead to dangling references if you don't pay attention during refactoring which may happen at a later point. Example:

```
operator std::string & (void) { std::string result = "x" + s; return result; } // dangerous!
```

I guess operator overloading just adds confusion here. Just imagine the function to be declared `std::string & ToString()`, and everything should become clearer.